# Link onClick event needs to show just one DIV

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have this code, works fine but the problem is when I click on link (1) shows all the DIVs while I need each Link showing ONLY its own div.

Java Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
});

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a> //Link(1)
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a>//Link(2)
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a>//Link(3)
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
</div>
//...............And so on.....
```

If I click on any of those links it shows all the DIVs while it should show just its own one.

How to do that?

Comment: Replace `"$(.slidingDiv").slideToggle()` with `$(this).next().slideToggle()` - you're targeting all members of the slidingDiv class and not just the one following the clicked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting all elements with `slidingDiv` `class`, Change below code

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

As below and try

```
$(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

**Update*:**

You have `show_hide` `class` as child of `slidingDiv` to handle it's `click event` try below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        var div =  $(this).next(".slidingDiv");
        console.log(div);
        if (!div.length) {
            div = $(this).parent('.slidingDiv');
        }
        console.log(div);
        div.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/MVP9V/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

### HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a> //Link(1)
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide1</a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a>//Link(2)
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide2</a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a>//Link(3)
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide3</a>
</div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(this).next().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrvXB/